# EF run Seed method without model changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I have a webAPI hosted in Azure as my back-end. I am using Code-First to create my entities. I can pre-feed my DB fine via the seed method, but if I am done with my model changes and then remember that I need to add something to the seed, there is no way to run the seed method.
Multiple posts suggest the simple run update-database. I do see: "Running Seed method." and then publish to azure, my table is still empty. And I don't want to change the models just to trigger the seed, because that is just not clean solution.

I have already tried using each of the commented lines but no avail

```
    public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext")
    {
        //Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, MyProject.Migrations.Configuration>("DefaultConnection"));
        //Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>());
    }
```

is there something I should be doing at the azure side or it just plainly doesn't work unless I change one my models!?

## Update1:

I already the migrations folder and follow the commands to enable it and update the db and when I have a model change, the db updates just fine. That works, no issue there. The only issue if I want to add things to the seed method and I want to execute it without having to change my model.

Comment: What are you publishing to Azure, your project or the DB? Can you create a local copy of the DB, connect to that, and see if it gets updated?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using code first then you can manage and handle all your migrations easily.

you need to type "enable-migrations" using package manger console.After this you will have a folder named Migrations.

Check this [link](http://asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3) for additional information.

Let know if you have any issues.